# Different looks of two different PDF

Tags: pdftex

The first image is my text. The second one is of a professor. Mine looks different from his: my characters are a bit bolder than his and not as easy looking (and reading) as his, perhaps due to different font and font size. I looked at other texts and it seems to me that my text looks odd, whereas the one of that professor is kind of "standard". Why does that happen?

I use MikTex's portable version 2.9. I use the following packages in my .tex:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
```

Please feel free to add or edit tags, because I don't know which tags should be used for my question.

[image: My text]

[image: Other's text]

Comment: Try removing `\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}`

Comment: Yes,  your professor probably uses the default Computer Modern, or Latin Modern fonts . Why do you prefer the latter? Aesthetically speaking, there is no ‘standard’. It's a matter of personal taste, and as far as I'm concerned, I'm fed up by  Times-derived fonts as well as Computer Modern. But it's only my taste.

Comment: @Bernard: I don't know but the latter is easier to read for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The professor's document uses the standard LaTeX font, which is obtained without adding any font package. In your case, you get (a clone of) Times New Roman because of

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

Remove that line and your document will use the Computer Modern font, like the professor's.